# How to remove device from Google?

Tags: google-play-store, google, android-device-manager

I have given away one of my devices, I'd like to remove it from my Google account entirely. It seems, there is no longer a way to do this (which, if true, probably breaks GDPR).

I'm aware I can "hide" the device at https://play.google.com/settings/ by unchecking "Show in menus" but I actually want to remove the device from my account entirely.

Edit: I'm also aware I can remove the device from Recent Devices at https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity, to prevent that device from accessing the Google account. The device is already not in that list. This does not remove the device from all of Google's databases, as it still exists in Google Play, for example.

I've checked https://www.google.com/apps/mydevices/b/0 which used to be the place to do this, but it no longer works, and there is notice to use https://www.google.com/android/find However, that does not provide an option to remove the device from your account - only to erase it etc.

Any idea how to remove a device, or contact Google to remove a device?

Answer (score 1):

Log into your account and click this

https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity

**[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/-gUd17mppc)**

It works for me. I don't think GDPR 
 should make a difference, else that would have been widely reported

[image]

(Click to enlarge)

Comment: The device I want to remove isn't in that list, but is in the list at https://play.google.com/settings/ Furthermore, removing any other device from that list, also doesn't make it disappear from the list at  https://play.google.com/settings/ So it appears they're not connected. Seems like devices that have access to your account vs devices listed on your account are different things in Google's eyes.

Comment: updated answer from horse's mouth (google) so that there is no doubt (see source linked)

Comment: That link just removes it from device activity, hence /device-activity in the URL, and the title on the page "Recently used devices". It removes that device's access to the Google account, it does not actually remove the entire device from all of Google's databases, as it still exists in Google Play, maybe other places. My question is not specific to Google Play, but that's certainly one area I can still see my device. I do not simply want to remove the device from recent devices, if I did, I would have asked that, I want to remove it from everywhere.

Comment: It's also pretty clear I didn't mean just Google Play, because I can also see the device at https://www.google.com/android/find